# Dynamically add JAR to Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, android, ant, gradle, android-studio

Currently, my build.gradle has a dependency on an external library built with Ant. To accomplish building the library, I followed the advice [here](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2011/09/18/using-gradle-to-bootstrap-your-legacy-ant-builds/) and created a task which builds the external library, and copies it to the libs/ folder.

The task is called as part of a `dependency`:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree('libs') {
        include '*.jar'
        builtBy 'myTask'
    }
}

task myTask (type: GradleBuild) { GradleBuild antBuild ->
    antBuild.buildFile('external-stub.gradle')
    antBuild.tasks = ['clean', 'ivy.check', 'ivy.download', 'ivy.task', 'ivy',
    'init', 'mergeCode', 'compile', 'jar', 'copyJarsToProject']
}
```

However, when the compile actually runs, the library I just built and copied in is not included in the dependencies, as evidenced by a whole lot of compilation errors.

Am I including the library the wrong way?

The full build.gradle and associated files are over at Github, and I've linked to the specific commit I'm having issues with: [Source Repository](https://github.com/MinimalBible/MinimalBible/tree/77c797d4f1621511f659557397f597fd0843a6f6/MinimalBible)

Comment: Please note that the build does work if the built jar pre-exists in the libs/ directory. That is, starting from a clean working tree, the build fails. Re-trying the build after a failure is successful, because the external jar has already been built.

Comment: The dependencies declared for a project have no effect outside that project, let alone outside that build.

Comment: I understand. The task is building the external library, which copies to the current project. Theoretically, then the current project should depend on the library which was just generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, took me a while to get a build I was happy with. But, here's what was changed.

The actual build of the JAR was built using the same style, but moved to the external project (so that the main build project wasn't reaching across to it). I'll give an in-depth explanation below, but the commits are [here](https://github.com/MinimalBible/jsword-minimalbible/commit/7e0eaee2015dfccf63c7b2f458bdb8bfba4033ad) and [here](https://github.com/MinimalBible/jsword-minimalbible/commit/4f03086a36c82f84e1258880b2a574ca566b5094). These are in order.

Basically, we export the jar as an artifact that other projects can depend on, rather than copying over the Jar ourselves. This way, the Ant build runs and other projects can see the Jar we just created. This is the end of the first commit. In the second commit, the task outputs are marked as needing to be regenerated only if the Jar does not exist. This was due to the fact that whenever I tried to build the app, it would take minutes to regen the Jar, and then have to repackage everything else as well. The code is below:

**build.gradle** *External Project*

```
configurations {
    buildJSword
}

task doBuildJSword (type: GradleBuild) {
buildFile = 'jsword-stub.gradle'
tasks = ['clean', 'ivy.check', 'ivy.download', 'ivy.task', 'ivy',
    'init', 'mergeCode', 'compile', 'jar'] //, 'copyJarsToMinimalBible']
    ext.outputJar = file('distribution/jsword.jar')
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        ext.outputJar.exists()
    }
}

artifacts {
    buildJSword(doBuildJSword.ext.outputJar) {
        builtBy doBuildJSword
    }
}
```

Then, the main project just has to add this project as a compile-time dependency:

**build.gradle** *Main Project*

```
compile project(path: ':jsword-minimalbible', configuration: 'buildJSword')
```

Hope this is helpful for anyone with a similar issue, let me know if you have questions!

**Note:** The build currently does not clean itself properly, so if you change any code in the external project, you need to delete the external Jar for everything to regenerate itself correctly.

Comment: As a quick update: Using Gradle 2 requires us to change the name from doBuildJSword to compileJava. `s/doBuildJSword/compileJava/` is enough to perform the change.